# can not insert hebrew in mysql db version 5.1.56 community with php version 5.2.1

Tags: php, mysql, hebrew

can not insert hebrew in mysql db version 5.1.56 community  with php version 5.2.1

Only getting question mark after insert.

Comment: You should try with 
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: this link will help you